# SAS Logit Function

Tags: sas

I can see in sas there is a logistic() function that calculates the inverse-logit(x).

```
logistic(x) = exp(x)/(exp(x)+1)
```

Is there a function that calculates logit(x)?

```
logit(x) = log(p/1-p)
```

Comment: Do you mean `log(p/(1-p))` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is not, but `proc fcmp` lets you create functions.

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.stats;
    function logit(p);

        if(0 < p < 1) then do;
            result = log(p/(1-p));
            return(result);
        end;
            else put "ERROR: Invalid argument to logit function.";

    endsub;
run;

data _null_;
    logit = logit(0.2);
    put logit;
run;
```

**A breakdown of how to save and load custom functions:**

1. `options cmplib=work.funcs;`

Load custom functions from the dataset `work.funcs`, if it exists.

2. `proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.stats;`

Output and append custom functions to a dataset named `funcs`. The 3-level `outlib` statement is a bit confusing since it's actually creating a hierarchical dataset.

**The Three-Level Name**

`one.two.three`

`one`: Output library name

`two`: Dataset name to hold custom functions

`three`: An identifier package name to be added to the dataset. We're calling this the `stats` package.

If you open up the dataset `work.funcs`, you will see the `stats` package within the column labeled `_Key_`.